# How can I find which Office license key was installed?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I have four computers and for each one I have a license key for Office 2007 Professional.

I want to format my PC but I'm afraid that if I do, I won't know which key to re-install!

Is there any way to find out which key I'm currently using for Office 2007 Professional? I use Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool called "Magic Jelly Bean - KeyFinder" for which the free edition will do the job for you, and even provide a printed report as well as letting you save the information in an ASCII text file:

Magic Jelly Bean - KeyFinder
  http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Answer (score 6):

The Super User Blog [covered this recently](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/03/dude-where-are-my-keys/)—comparing several tools.

(EDIT: As Requested) The three tools reviewed:

- [Key Finder Thing](http://ychatsharp.com/kft)
- [License Crawler](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler.htm)
- [Product Key Finder](http://davehope.co.uk/projects/product-key-finder/)

and also referenced [Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/).

Comment: while the SU blog is off course excellent, I'd add a short list of the tools mentioned in the blog post, so users get an idea what is in that post.

Comment: @Ivo: Good point...

Comment: The Product Key Finder is the only one of these that will extract the Office key for free